# How to throw exception for sync callback in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, try-catch

I want to throw an error exception for an redis.set callback and catch in try-catch block and then get control to error handling express middleware.

```
try {
  redis.get('key', (err, reply) => { 
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!reply) throw new Error('Can't find key');
  });
}
catch{
  next(error);
}
```

the problem is, that try-catch is simply not working, error is going to node console, but server is responding with 200 status.

Comment: How do you call this code? How do you send response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant catch async events. Use promises for that:

```
const getKey = new Promise((res,rej) => {
  redis.get('key', (err, reply) => { 
    if(err) return rej(err);
    res(reply);
  });
});
```

So one can do:

```
getKey.catch(next);

getKey.then(reply => {
  //do whatever
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know, that this callback is async.